# Unable to retain the table values after refreshing the browser window

Tags: javascript, html

Created a form using html, javascript. After entering the fields, when i click submit button, it saves the user data in localstorage and updates the table rows dynamically. But once i refresh the browser, the table holding the information of all users is lost. I want to retain the table after refreshing the browser.
[Click here to view screenshot of page Before refresh](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lojgt.png)

[Click here to view screenshot of page After refresh](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uLenu.png)

JS Code :

```
 var testObject = [];
    var users = {};

    function clear(){
       document.getElementById("uname").value = "";
       document.getElementById("email").value = "";
       document.getElementById("pass").value = "";
       document.getElementById("loc").value = "";
       document.getElementById("org").value = "";
       document.getElementById("m").checked = false;
       document.getElementById("f").checked = false;
    }
    function IsValid(username,usermail,password,location,organization,gender){ 
      if(username!="" && usermail!="" && password!="" && location!="" && organization!="" && gender!=""){
        return true;
      }
    }
    function removeDivChild(str)
    {
      if(document.getElementById(str).querySelector('p')){ 
        document.getElementById(str).lastElementChild.remove();
        }
    }
    function appendToDiv(val,cdiv)
    {
      if(val=="" && document.getElementById(cdiv).querySelector('p')==null)
          {
            var node = document.createElement("P");
            if(document.getElementById(cdiv).className=="textbox"){
                var text = document.createTextNode("please enter " + document.getElementById(cdiv).lastElementChild.placeholder);
            }
            else if(document.getElementById(cdiv).className=="radiobox"){
                var text = document.createTextNode("please enter gender");
               }
             node.appendChild(text);
            document.getElementById(cdiv).appendChild(node);
              }
             if(val!="" && document.getElementById(cdiv).querySelector('p')!=null)
             {
            document.getElementById(cdiv).lastElementChild.remove();
             }
    }
    function save(){
           var userval = document.getElementById("uname").value;
           var eval = document.getElementById("email").value;
           var passval = document.getElementById("pass").value;
           var locval = document.getElementById("loc").value;
           var orgval = document.getElementById("org").value;  
           var genval = "";
           if(document.getElementById("m").checked){
                 genval = document.getElementById("m").value;
           }
            if(document.getElementById("f").checked)
           {
             genval = document.getElementById("f").value;
           }
          if(IsValid(userval,eval,passval,locval,orgval,genval))
         {
          users["uname"] = userval; 
          removeDivChild("userdiv");
          users["email"] = eval; 
          removeDivChild("maildiv");
          users["pass"] = passval; 
          removeDivChild("passdiv");
          users["loc"] = locval; 
          removeDivChild("locdiv");
          users["org"] = orgval; 
          removeDivChild("orgdiv");
          users["gender"] = genval; 
          removeDivChild("gendiv");
          testObject.push(users);

          updateTable();
         }     
         else
         {
          appendToDiv(userval,"userdiv");  
          appendToDiv(eval,"maildiv");  
          appendToDiv(passval,"passdiv");  
          appendToDiv(locval,"locdiv");
          appendToDiv(orgval,"orgdiv");  
          appendToDiv(genval,"gendiv");  
         }
       }
          function updateTable(){
            localStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify(testObject));
            var usr = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
            var i = testObject.length-1;       
            if(i==0){
              var nodeh = document.createElement("tr");
              var usernode = document.createElement("th");
              var usertext = document.createTextNode("Username");
              usernode.appendChild(usertext);
              nodeh.appendChild(usernode);
              var enode = document.createElement("th");
              var etext = document.createTextNode("Email");
              enode.appendChild(etext);
              nodeh.appendChild(enode);
              var pnode = document.createElement("th");
              var ptext = document.createTextNode("Password");
              pnode.appendChild(ptext);
              nodeh.appendChild(pnode);
              var lnode = document.createElement("th");
              var ltext = document.createTextNode("Location");
              lnode.appendChild(ltext);
              nodeh.appendChild(lnode);
              var onode = document.createElement("th");
              var otext = document.createTextNode("Organization");
              onode.appendChild(otext);
              nodeh.appendChild(onode);
              var gnode = document.createElement("th");
              var gtext = document.createTextNode("gender");
              gnode.appendChild(gtext);
              nodeh.appendChild(gnode);
              document.getElementById("t").appendChild(nodeh);
            }
            var noder = document.createElement("tr");
            var nodeu = document.createElement("td");
            var textu = document.createTextNode(usr[i].uname);
            nodeu.appendChild(textu);
            noder.appendChild(nodeu);
            var nodee = document.createElement("td");
            var texte = document.createTextNode(usr[i].email);
            nodee.appendChild(texte);
            noder.appendChild(nodee);
            var nodep = document.createElement("td");
            var textp = document.createTextNode(usr[i].pass);
            nodep.appendChild(textp);
            noder.appendChild(nodep);
            var nodel = document.createElement("td");
            var textl = document.createTextNode(usr[i].loc);
            nodel.appendChild(textl);
            noder.appendChild(nodel);
            var nodeo = document.createElement("td");
            var texto = document.createTextNode(usr[i].org);
            nodeo.appendChild(texto);
            noder.appendChild(nodeo);
            var nodeg = document.createElement("td");
            var textg = document.createTextNode(usr[i].gender);
            nodeg.appendChild(textg);
            noder.appendChild(nodeg);
            document.getElementById("t").appendChild(noder);
            clear(); 
          }
```

HTML code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="form.css">
</head>
<body>  

    <script src="check.js"></script>

    <div id="userdiv" class="textbox">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Username" id="uname" name="Username">
    </div>
    <div id="maildiv" class="textbox">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Email" id="email" name="Email">
    </div>
    <div id="passdiv" class="textbox">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Password" id="pass" name="Password">
    </div>
     <div id="locdiv" class="textbox">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Location" id="loc" name="Location">
     </div>
      <div id="orgdiv" class="textbox">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Organization" id="org" name="Organization">
        </div>
      <div id="gendiv" class="radiobox">
        <input type="radio" name="gender" id="m" value="male"/> Male
        <input type="radio" name="gender" id="f" value="female"/> Female
      </div>
    <button id="submit" onclick="save()">Submit</button>
    <table id="t" border="1">
    </table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You need to persist your state to storage. Try taking a look at [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

Comment: Which method should i use exactly to persist the state..(checked the link, couldn't find any)

Comment: i used similar method as u can see in my code :

localStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify(testObject));  // line no.73

Comment: You need to pull it out of localStorage too

Comment: Please check the next line as well...i am retrieving the array of objects using "user" key from localstorage
var usr = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));

Comment: First, you set the local storage using `testObject` which is an empty object when the page loads. Then immediately after setting it to your empty object, you pull it out and you get the empty object that _you just set_. Add a load routine that pulls your object out of localStorage when the page loads. Pull the call to save out of `updateTable`  and put it in save, that's where it belongs.

Comment: sorry..i didn't understand the last line you're trying to convey "Pull the call to save out of updateTable and put it in save, that's where it belongs"

Comment: i tried adding onload event to table element as well..it didn't work

<table onload="updateTable()">
</table>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the back and forth in the comments on your question I decided to just create an example from your code sample. Most of it was untouched however I did add comments to the things that I did change.

```js
// I moved the declaration of the testObject below to let the functions be created first
// so i can use teh new loadFromStorage function to create the object
var users = {};

// This is a new function I created
function loadFromStorage() {
 // parse the 'user' object in local storage, if its empty return an empty array
 return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user')) || [];
}

function clear() {
 // I didn't touch this function
  document.getElementById("uname").value = "";
  document.getElementById("email").value = "";
  document.getElementById("pass").value = "";
  document.getElementById("loc").value = "";
  document.getElementById("org").value = "";
  document.getElementById("m").checked = false;
  document.getElementById("f").checked = false;
}

function IsValid(username, usermail, password, location, organization, gender) {
 // I didn't touch this function
  if (username != "" && usermail != "" && password != "" && location != "" && organization != "" && gender != "") {
    return true;
  }
}

function removeDivChild(str) {
 // I didn't touch this function
  if (document.getElementById(str).querySelector('p')) {
    document.getElementById(str).lastElementChild.remove();
  }
}

function appendToDiv(val, cdiv) {
 // I didn't touch this function
  if (val == "" && document.getElementById(cdiv).querySelector('p') == null) {
    var node = document.createElement("P");
    if (document.getElementById(cdiv).className == "textbox") {
      var text = document.createTextNode("please enter " + document.getElementById(cdiv).lastElementChild.placeholder);
    } else if (document.getElementById(cdiv).className == "radiobox") {
      var text = document.createTextNode("please enter gender");
    }
    node.appendChild(text);
    document.getElementById(cdiv).appendChild(node);
  }
  if (val != "" && document.getElementById(cdiv).querySelector('p') != null) {
    document.getElementById(cdiv).lastElementChild.remove();
  }
}

// Changes in this function
function save() {
  var userval = document.getElementById("uname").value;
  var eval = document.getElementById("email").value;
  var passval = document.getElementById("pass").value;
  var locval = document.getElementById("loc").value;
  var orgval = document.getElementById("org").value;
  var genval = "";
  if (document.getElementById("m").checked) {
    genval = document.getElementById("m").value;
  }
  if (document.getElementById("f").checked) {
    genval = document.getElementById("f").value;
  }
  if (IsValid(userval, eval, passval, locval, orgval, genval)) {
    users["uname"] = userval;
    removeDivChild("userdiv");
    users["email"] = eval;
    removeDivChild("maildiv");
    users["pass"] = passval;
    removeDivChild("passdiv");
    users["loc"] = locval;
    removeDivChild("locdiv");
    users["org"] = orgval;
    removeDivChild("orgdiv");
    users["gender"] = genval;
    removeDivChild("gendiv");
    testObject.push(users);
  // Saving testObject to the persistent storage here because this is where it belongs
    localStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify(testObject));
    
    updateTable();
  } else {
    appendToDiv(userval, "userdiv");
    appendToDiv(eval, "maildiv");
    appendToDiv(passval, "passdiv");
    appendToDiv(locval, "locdiv");
    appendToDiv(orgval, "orgdiv");
    appendToDiv(genval, "gendiv");
  }
}

// Changes in this function
function updateTable() {
  // pulled out the saving and the loading of user from localStorage here, 
  // everything should already be saved or loaded by the time we call
  // this function.
  
  // Also re-wrote this function because it was messy and hard to read, always remember you write code for humans not computers so slightly longer variable names that are descriptive are really good.
  
  // get a reference to the table
  var tbl = document.getElementById('t');
  // remove all the child rows, except for the header
  // CSS Selector explained:
  //    #t - find the table by the id (you used t)
  //     > tr > td - find all td's that are direct children of the t table
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('#t > tr > td'), function(node) { 
   node.parentNode.removeChild( node ); 
  })
  
  // loop over all the 'users' in 'testObject'
  for(var i = 0; i < testObject.length; i++){
   // store a reference to the current object to make the code easier to read
   var currentObject = testObject[i];
    // create the TR
    var tr = document.createElement('tr');
    // Create the td's
    var tdUserName = document.createElement('td');
    var tdEmail = document.createElement('td');
    var tdPassword = document.createElement('td');
    var tdLocation = document.createElement('td');
    var tdOrganization = document.createElement('td');
    var tdGender = document.createElement('td');
    // create the text nodes
    var userName = document.createTextNode(currentObject.uname);
    var email = document.createTextNode(currentObject.email);
    var password = document.createTextNode(currentObject.pass);
    var location = document.createTextNode(currentObject.loc);
    var organization = document.createTextNode(currentObject.org);
    var gender = document.createTextNode(currentObject.gender);
    // add the elements to their containers
    tdUserName.appendChild(userName);
    tdEmail.appendChild(email);
    tdPassword.appendChild(password);
    tdLocation.appendChild(location);
    tdOrganization.appendChild(organization);
    tdGender.appendChild(gender);
    // add the td's to the row
    tr.appendChild(tdUserName);
    tr.appendChild(tdEmail);
    tr.appendChild(tdPassword);
    tr.appendChild(tdLocation);
    tr.appendChild(tdOrganization);
    tr.appendChild(tdGender);
    // add the row to the table 
    tbl.appendChild(tr);
  }
  
  // call your clear function
  clear();
}

// load the object from storage
var testObject = loadFromStorage();

// populate the table
updateTable();
```

```html
<div id="userdiv" class="textbox">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Username" id="uname" name="Username">
</div>
<div id="maildiv" class="textbox">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Email" id="email" name="Email">
</div>
<div id="passdiv" class="textbox">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Password" id="pass" name="Password">
</div>
<div id="locdiv" class="textbox">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Location" id="loc" name="Location">
</div>
<div id="orgdiv" class="textbox">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Organization" id="org" name="Organization">
</div>
<div id="gendiv" class="radiobox">
  <input type="radio" name="gender" id="m" value="male" /> Male
  <input type="radio" name="gender" id="f" value="female" /> Female
</div>
<button id="submit" onclick="save()">Submit</button>
<!-- Added the header to the table, it isn't removed now when rebuilding it -->
<table id="t" border="1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>Username</td>
      <td>Email</td>
      <td>Password</td>
      <td>Location</td>
      <td>Organization</td>
      <td>Gender</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

Here is a link to a JSFiddle because this example wont run properly because it accesses localStorage but is sandboxed. [Working Example](https://jsfiddle.net/n0etpLhv/)

Comment: It is able to retain the values after page reload...but the thing is, i want the table(with previously stored information) to show up after refresh...your code is able to show the retained information, but only after i click submit button..i want to show it before i click submit

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. When you load the page it takes the information that was stored and load it. It is only stored after it is saved. Save is what adds it to the list of items and sends it to the persistent storage. Are you saying you want the values in the textboxes to store their state? so when you refresh the page the items in the textboxes are loaded again?

Comment: The program is running successfully now....! No bugs or issues..

But still wondering,how the querySelectorAll('#t > tr > td') removed extra rows that pop up after page reload..

Comment: That selector breaks down like this:
`#t` finds the table by id. `> tr` finds trs that are direct children of the table. `> td` finds the tds that are direct children of the tr. The reason it skips the header row is because the header is under a `thead` tag.